Sending/ Posting data from Claude.ai or OpenAI to my custom API endpoint
I want to register the user once they have provided valid data such as their name and email address using chat approach such as offered by OpenAI/ Claude.ai etc.
Are these capable of sending the data to my API endpoint or how do I know that the conversation has ended and I can register the user?
Any help will be highly appreciated.
